# Waiting for page to load selenium, Python. All the pages have the same structure

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape some data using selenium and python. I have a list with some links and I have to go through every link. What I do now is the following:

```
for link in links:
    self.page_driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(5)
    #scrape data
```

It works just fine, the problem is that I have a lot of links and waiting 5 seconds for each one is a waste of time. That's why I decided to try with something like:

```
self.driver.get(link)
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cell-box'))
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    logging.info("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

The problem is that every link has the exact same structure inside, only data change, so the element is found even if the page hasn't changed. What I would like to do is to save the name of the product in the link in a variable, change page wait until the name of the product is different than the one saved, which means the new page loaded. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `staleness_of` `Expected Condition`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
element = None
for link in links:
    self.page_driver.get(link)
    if (element is not None):
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element)
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cell-box')))
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.info("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    #scrape data
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element)` raises the TimeoutException. Maybe I am doing something wrong. The pages I am trying to scrapy are similar to this one: [link](http://www.maijia.com/index.html#/shop/item/?itemId=45302792713) and inside the try statement I put: `element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="module-shop-item"]')))` .